# How to pass a python variable to shell script

Tags: python, bash, shell, unix

I have a shell script with `first.sh` and it calls a python script `second.py` internally. While this python script executes it sets some variable `var='yes'` based on certain parameters.

now i need to pass this var variable to shell script which it is calling and do some processing . Please let me know how to do such.

I tried `os.system(‘bash’)`, but it is creating a new session and the execution of the shell script is not continuing.

Answer (score 0):

A common pattern for this is to use file descriptors between the parent process (bash) and the child (python). In the simple case, just using standard input/output.  So bash could read the result.  Something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
foo=$(python script.py)
echo "$foo"
```

If you need something more complex than a single variable, you will need to decide on some formatting for the data and how to process it (maybe output in json?)

Comment: `$( ... )` [should be used in place of backticks](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete), all-caps names are [defined by POSIX to be used for variables that modify shell or OS behavior](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html) and parameter expansions should *always* be in double quotes, even when passing to `echo` -- see [BashPitfalls #14](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#echo_.24foo).

Comment: Good callout.  This was a quick hack of an example.  Will update.

Comment: But what if i have more the one variable in the python program,can this be taken care ?

Comment: @Corework, lots of possible ways to do that already elsewhere in our knowledgebase. Personally, I suggest duplicating the format of `/proc/self/environ` -- using NUL-delimited `key=value` pairs -- and using a [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001)-style loop to read them out and assign to an associative array.

Comment: If you have `jq` installed, you could output in json format and use `jq` to parse out the things you care about.  But as @CharlesDuffy pointed out, there is a lot of ways to do this (data marshaling) and is going to depend a lot on the type of data you are passing, and what tools you have.